# Forgot to branch in git, need to move changes from master

Tags: git, git-branch

I eagerly ducked into code mode and modified some files, but neglected to branch from master first.  The mods aren't so extensive that I can't redo them, but what's a good way of taking my (so far, uncommitted) changes in master and migrating them to a new branch, leaving master untouched in the end?

Comment: [**Dude.**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Forgot+to+branch+in+git%2C+need+to+move+changes+from+master). This question appears to be off-topic because googling the title produces excellent answers.

Comment: @jthill I found this question through a google search.  Am I stuck in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If not yet committed anywhere (`git status` shows a bunch of stuff modified, it's OK if it's "git add"-ed too):

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
```

Despite the name `checkout` this usage (with `-b`) does not check anything out.  The `-b` flag says "create a new branch", so git creates the branch-name and makes it correspond to the current `HEAD` commit.  Then it makes `HEAD` point to the new branch, and stops there.

Your next commit is therefore on `newbranch`, which has as its parent commit, the commit you were on when you started modifying files.  So assuming you were on `master`, and you had these commits:

```
A - B - C       <-- HEAD=master
```

the `checkout -b` makes this read:

```
A - B - C       <-- master, HEAD=newbranch
```

and a later commit adds a new commit `D`:

```
A - B - C       <-- master
          \
            D   <-- newbranch
```

Answer (score 6):

```
git branch -M master my-branch
```

> With a `-m` or `-M` option, `<oldbranch>` will be renamed to `<newbranch>`. If `<oldbranch>` had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed to match `<newbranch>`, and a reflog entry is created to remember the branch renaming. If `<newbranch>` exists, `-M` must be used to force the rename to happen.

[Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

and then

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

or

```
git branch master my-branch  (or another ref)
```

Comment: That's a good way to change stuff that was *committed* to be on the new branch `my-branch`.

Answer (score 3):

```
git stash
git stash branch <branchname>
```

Comment: That will work, but `git checkout -b <branchname>` is simpler (and a bit faster, it does not have to undo changes and then re-apply them).