# Problem merging branch into master in git

Tags: git

I have a master with files A, B, C
I have a branch called 'feature' with files: D,E,F.

Yes my branch was NOT cut off of my master, so the files are nothing alike between branch and master.

Now I want to essentially replace the content of my master with what's in branch.

What can I do?

Comment: Heya! This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19612439/1004631

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the current Git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+replace+branch+master

Comment: Actually I simply did merge feature and it merged successfully. Replace is no different from merge it seems.

Comment: Just merge master in your branch and then try merging it in master. Resolve conflicts on step1 if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

`git checkout feature
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge feature`

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 0):

> I want to...replace the content of my `master` with what's in [`feature`]

Sounds like you don't want to merge at all.  I would do this:

```
git checkout master
git tag old-master
git reset --hard feature
```

A branch in git is not a container for files: It's nothing but a name for a particular commit.

The `git checkout master` command does two things;

1. It makes the workspace look like whatever the `master` commit says it's supposed to look like, but we don't care about that, and
2. It makes `master` be the "current" branch.

The `git tag old-master` command is optional:  It makes a new name (`old-master`) for the commit that's about to not be `master` anymore, just in case you might ever want to find it again.

`git reset --hard feature` is the money command: It does two things;

1. It changes the current branch (`master`) to refer to the same commit that `feature` refers to, and
2. It re-checks it out, making the workspace look like what the master/feature commit says it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

if you replacing the full contents of master with feature than you need to remove everything from the master then, right? than this should do:

```
git checkout master
git rm -rf *
git merge feature
```